Spring Auth entry point not overriding abstracted commence method
I'm in the middle of implementing JWT authentication in my Spring server, but am getting an error when trying to define an entry point for the JWT token checking:

Below is my code, it seems to me that my method is correctly overriding AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence()?
package letterbookd.server.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
            }
}

Any ideas on how to solve this issue would be much appreciated!

Ironically I find the answer to my question basically instantly after posting 
Turns out my version of spring's AuthenticationEntryPoint uses jakarta instead of javax (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html).
This code has fixed all my issues it seems:

package letterbookd.server.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
            }
}


